# gRPC in Net 6.0. Where is Startup.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc

i am trying to do a simple application of gRPC with Net 6.0, and in the documentation I can read the I have to configure the end points in the StartUp.cs file. But it seems it is for the version 5.x of DotNet.

[This is the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Well, I have created a gRPC project in Visual Studio 2022, with the template ASP Core gPRC Service. But in this case, I don't see the StartUp.cs file, I only can see the program.cs file.

How could I create a gRPC service with Visual Studio 2022 and Net 6?

Thanks.

Comment: With the new minimal API, the reduced contents of the startup.cs file are moved to the program.cs file. Minimal API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: You can use the program.cs and startup.cs file from a template generated for .NET 5, it should work with .NET 6 without modifications

Comment: look at https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/grpc/test-tools/Startup.cs